# gibberish on oracle 12.1 db sqlplus errors

Tags: oracle, unicode, sqlplus, oracle12c, nls-lang

I am getting gebbrish on my sqlplus ORA errors. Example:

```
SQL> conn ur@mydb
Enter password:
ERROR:
ORA-01017: ┐┐┐┐┐ ┐┐┐┐┐/┐┐┐┐┐ ┐┐ ┐┐┐┐┐; ┐┐┐┐┐┐┐┐ ┐┐┐┐┐
```

this is my nls_lang on the registry:
AMERICAN_AMERICA.WE8MSWIN1252

I have windows 8 64 bit. Oracle db 12.1.0.1.
Tried everything.

Thank you for the help.

Comment: I assume your local settings are populated to database after successfull logon, i.e. it does not apply before successfull authentification.

Comment: Are you working locally on one machine? There is a problem when your database is version 11.1 or higher and has SEC_CASE_SENSITIVE_LOGON = TRUE (Password is case-sensitive) but your Oracle Client is version 10 or earlier.

Comment: Yes, i am working locally on one machine. No client installed but the default with the database software

Comment: The gibbrish happens also for example on a "select *;" query after logon.

Comment: with what character set was the database created?

Comment: AL32UTF8 is my database character set. I checked it with the select NLS_CHARACTERSET from nls_database_parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Try: I had the same problem, solved when I changed the `NLS_VALUE` to `AMERICAN_AMERICA.WE8MSWIN1252`

```
Procedure
Run the following queries to get the corresponding values:
SELECT VALUE as Language FROM NLS_DATABASE_PARAMETERS WHERE PARAMETER='NLS_LANGUAGE';
SELECT VALUE as Territory FROM NLS_DATABASE_PARAMETERS WHERE PARAMETER='NLS_TERRITORY';
SELECT VALUE as Characterset FROM NLS_DATABASE_PARAMETERS WHERE PARAMETER='NLS_CHARACTERSET';
The NLS_LANG parameter is set as: <Language>_<Territory>.<Characterset> (for example, set NLS_LANG = AMERICAN_AMERICA.UTF8)

To set the value of the NLS_LANG parameter in Windows, verify the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/SOFTWARE/ORACLE/NLS_LANG entry in the registry.
To set the value of the NLS_LANG parameter in UNIX, NLS_LANG is set as a local environment variable
```

source: http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/ssfs/v9r2/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.help.install.doc%2Ft_ConfiguringTheNLS_LANGParameterForAnOracleClient.html